# Animate window after it has been hidden

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to create window that is animated when it is opened/closed. So far I have succeeded and with help of SO community come up with solution where I use attached behaviors
to animate my window something like this:

```
public class NotificationWindowBehavior : Behavior<Window>
{
//Here I define some properties, which I have omitted for simplicity
  
    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();
        this.AssociatedObject.Loaded += this.OnLoaded;
        this.AssociatedObject.Closing += this.OnClosing;
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        base.OnDetaching();
        this.AssociatedObject.Loaded -= this.OnLoaded;
        this.AssociatedObject.Closing -= this.OnClosing;
    }

    private void OnLoaded(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        FadeInAnimation.Begin(AssociatedObject);

    }
    private void OnClosing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;

        FadeOutAnimation.Completed += eventHandler;
        FadeOutAnimation.Begin(AssociatedObject);

        void eventHandler(object s, EventArgs er)
        {
            FadeOutAnimation.Completed -= eventHandler;
            this.AssociatedObject.Hide();
        }
    }
}
```

And in xaml:

```
  <Window.Resources>              
    <Storyboard x:Key="FadeInAnimation">
        <DoubleAnimation
            Storyboard.Target="{Binding ElementName=Window}"
            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Window.Opacity)"
            Duration="0:0:0.3" From="0" To="1">
        </DoubleAnimation>
    </Storyboard>

    <Storyboard x:Key="FadeOutAnimation">
        <DoubleAnimation
            Storyboard.Target="{Binding ElementName=Window}"
            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Window.Opacity)"
            Duration="0:0:0.3" From="1" To="0">
        </DoubleAnimation>
    </Storyboard>       
</Window.Resources>

<i:Interaction.Behaviors>
    <Behaviors:NotificationWindowBehavior
        FadeInAnimation="{StaticResource FadeInAnimation}"
        FadeOutAnimation ="{StaticResource FadeOutAnimation}"
    </Behaviors:NotificationWindowBehavior>
</i:Interaction.Behaviors>
```

This works fine, but if I would like to create this window as reusable window that is only hidden and not closed the problem is that animation works only when window is first created. So current "solution" that I have come up is to check in some kind of windowService if window is hidden and then simply recreate animation like this:

```
if(_propertiesWindow.Visibility == Visibility.Hidden)
{
    var fadeInAnimation = new DoubleAnimation(1, new Duration(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 290)));
    Storyboard.SetTarget(fadeInAnimation, _propertiesWindow);
    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(fadeInAnimation, new PropertyPath(Window.OpacityProperty));
    var fadeInStoryBoard = new Storyboard();
    fadeInStoryBoard.Children.Add(fadeInAnimation);
    fadeInStoryBoard.Begin();
}
_propertiesWindow.Show();
```

I am trying to use MVVM approach and avoid code behind/limit knowledge about windows only to one particular windowService.
As said before this approach works, but I think it smells and would like to hear if it is somehow possible to reuse storyboard that was already defined in xaml so it could be used when window is being opened from hidden state. Or if there could be completely different approach for this problem?

Comment: From where are you currently calling `_propertiesWindow.Show()`?

Comment: @mm8 It is called from a method in windowService. This service is injected in some viewModels that need ability to open/close different windows.

Comment: Did you try to handle the `IsVisibleChanged` event for the window in the behaviour? Your issue should be matter of moving the code that creates the animation to a central location where it can be reused, right?

Comment: @mm8 Hmm, I will try it! Well, yes, I have duplicate code that does the same thing - I like the idea of attached behavior because that way I can move animation to xaml, but if  I still have to have some of this code in my windowService I might as well put all of it there and forget about attached behavior. That way I will have all logic in one place.